# Barcode Scanner in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, barcode-scanner

I'm trying to insert a barcode scanner in my `ListFragment` and use this tutorial: [BarcodeScanner](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/android-barcode-and-qr-scanner-example/)

But if I click on of the two buttons (QR or barcode-scan), it seems that my app doesn't find the downloaded `XZing` Barcode Scanner. But it is installed! I don't get an issue :-( ...
I think something is wrong in the `try-part`

Here is the code of my ListFragment:

```
    private Button b1;
    private Button b2;

    static final String ACTION_SCAN = "com.google.xzing.client.android.SCAN";

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        b1 = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.button_scan_barcode_ean);
        b2 = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.button_scan_qr_code);

      b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                scanQR(v);
            }
        });
        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                scanBar(v);
            }
        });
}

public void scanBar(View v){
        try {
            Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_SCAN);
            intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "PRODUCT_MODE");
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        }
        catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe){
            showDialog(getActivity(), "No Scanner Found", "Download a scanner code activity?", "Yes", "No").show();
        }
    }

    public void scanQR(View v){
        try {
            Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_SCAN);
            intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        }
        catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe){
            showDialog(getActivity(), "No Scanner Found", "Download a scanner code activity?", "Yes", "No").show();
        }
    }

    private static AlertDialog showDialog(final Activity act, CharSequence title,
                                          CharSequence message,
                                          CharSequence buttonYes,
                                          CharSequence buttonNo) {
        AlertDialog.Builder downloadDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(act);
        downloadDialog.setTitle(title);
        downloadDialog.setMessage(message);
        downloadDialog.setPositiveButton(buttonYes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                Uri uri = Uri.parse("market://search?q=pname:" + "com.google.zxing.client.android");
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                try {
                    act.startActivity(intent);
                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
                }
            }
        });
        downloadDialog.setNegativeButton(buttonNo, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

            }
        });
        return downloadDialog.show();
    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent){
        if (requestCode == 0){
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
                String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
                String format = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Content:" + contents + "Format" + format, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.show();
                final EditText editTextBarcode = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.editText_barcode);
                editTextBarcode.setText(contents);
            }
        }
    }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo in your ACTION_SCAN String. You wrote "xzing" instead of "zxing".

The correct String is

```
"com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN"
```

Comment: I'm such an idiot... I've searched my issue and doesn't seen this typo!
Thank you very much!!! You saved my little project!! :-)
Many greetings from Germany!